# JQuery not running on production in IE in ASP.NET MVC4 project

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm pretty confused.  I have a very simple menu, and on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` jquery uses `slideDown` and `slideUp` to show a submenu.

It works great on all browsers (including IE) running from Visual Studio. When i push it to our IIS server, it works fine on all browsers except for IE (tested on IE10 and IE11), which is really confusing me.

Here's the simple jquery in my _Layout:

```
<script>
    $('li.liSlide').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).children().next().slideDown();
    })
    $('li.liSlide').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children().next().slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

A sample sub menu:

```
<li class="liSlide">
    <a href="#">Batch</a>
    <ul>
         <li>@Html.ActionLink(((controller == "BatchSummary") ? "▷ " : "") + "Batch Summary", "BatchSummary", "BatchSummary")</li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

i tried setting an alert and updating some css to test if IE is getting into those functions, which it is not.  Does anyone know where I should begin to debug this?  I can post more relevant code as well.

Comment: do you get any error in javascript console?

Comment: Sounds like it could be an include issue.  Like Robert said, check the console for errors.  Also check the network tab (or similar, depending on your browser) for 404 errors on any included scripts.

Comment: What jquery version uses your MVC4 ?

Comment: I don't get anything in the console when i mouseover the menu

Comment: also in the network tab, nothing gets reported when i try the action

Answer (score 0):

From another question on this site:

`So for anyone out there who might run into the same issue and has to work with IE I solved the problem by adding this to my _layout.cshtml:`

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

`What this does is instructs IE to use the latest available rendering engine to process the html (in other words don't try to be smart and guess what my html is built for). So it essentially tells the versions of IE that have 'compatibility mode' to not use it.`

`For me this works fine because our organization is small and we are usually within one version of the latest release of IE. If the latest version causes issues, I can easy fix and deploy with no harm done. However, this IS NOT optimal for a general purpose website or organization with high numbers of users on a variety of IE browsers.`

this fixed it for me.